# No content to map due to end-of-input JSON parser Play framework

Tags: java, json, http, playframework, postman

I have a java play framework code in which I read json input passed through Html request body.

Here is the error:

```
[RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public Result register() {
        JsonNode json = Json.parse(request().body().asJson().asText());
        ...

        response().setContentType("application/json");
        return ok(index.render( "{\"authToken\":\"" + userHelper.getToken() + "\"}"));
    }
```

Line in which error occurs is this:

```
JsonNode json = Json.parse(request().body().asJson().asText());
```

and here is the json I send:

```
{"email":"something@something.something",
"password":"something",
"passwordConfirmation":"something",
"firstName":"something",
"lastName":"something",
"address":{
"streetName":"something",
"city":"something",
"country":"something"},
"phone":"something",
"gender":"something",
"birthdate":"something"}
```

I use Postman for sending PUT requests, and I've set both Content-type header and Accept header to application/json. I have no clue why is